# How to install libraries with Cxxdroid app

Tags: c, ide, libraries, smartphone

I am learning programming and am currently taking the CS50 course. I do not have a computer and have to learn on my phone. I am using the Cxxdroid app as my IDE and am trying to follow along with the CS50 course. I am at a part where I have to include <cs50.h> and when I try to compile the file I get an error saying it can't be found. I have downloaded the cs50 library off github and have placed it in the folder but I can't figure it out or find any documentation on how to get it to work.

When I click the install libraries it just gives me a list of a few available ones, not an option that I can add myself.

I know my situation is rather unique but I really want to make this work. Is there a better free IDE you know of for c?

I tried going into the .zip and pulling out the cs50.h file and placing it in the folder with my programs

Comment: cs50 provides a rather unique environment. Its libraries try to hide a lot from you. As far as I know it is hence important to follow the description for setting up your as provided by cs50. I recommend to contact your TA and ask for help there, they will know best. On the side, I suspect that doing the work on a phone will make it much harder for you, because on top of all those little problems which your fellow students will have to solve, you will have to solve a few/lot which almost nobody else has. I recommend to find a computer to do this on. Try a library, or - again - ask your TA.